# Add more native ads to existing facebook scroll ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, lazy-loading

I am trying to add more native ads to existing scroll in ios.

```
FBNativeAdsManager *manager = [[FBNativeAdsManager alloc] 
initWithPlacementID:@"Placement ID" forNumAdsRequested:5];
```

On initialising I put the `5` to load five ads. 
But, If user is scrolling through those ads, I want to lazy load more ads and add them to the same scroller.

The class `FBNativeAdDelegate` is used as a delegate of the scroll view. as mentioned on the link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/ios/nativescroll 
It contains a delegate which tells that user has scrolled till end.

```
- (void)nativeAdWillLogImpression:(FBNativeAd *)nativeAd{}
```

The above method gets called every time when a fresh ad appears on the screen. So I know if this method gets called fifth time, I have to load more ads to it.

But, how to add more ads to it?

Any relevant help and suggestions appreciated.
Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have checked, It cannot be done currently as facebook is using its own custom ads manager array which is added to scroll view later. Hope it helps.